# upload file/form on nginx configured tomcat

Tags: tomcat, nginx, https, tomcat7, reverse-proxy

I have nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) set up on my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

I want to upload a excel file through a form on nginx setup site , but there is no luck.Can anybody help me with configuration setup

my current nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default)configuration :

```
server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/self-signed.conf;
   # include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

location / {
 root /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT;

  index pbStartPage.jsp;

   }
location ~ /upload {
        limit_except POST             { deny all; }
        client_body_temp_path          /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/upload;
        client_body_in_file_only       on;
        client_body_buffer_size        128K;
        client_max_body_size           50M;
        proxy_pass_request_headers     on;
        proxy_set_header content-type "text/html";
        proxy_set_header               X-FILE $request_body_file;
        proxy_set_body                 $request_body_file;
        proxy_pass                     http://localhost:8088/;
        proxy_redirect                 off;

}

}
```

please help me if there is something need to be added to configuration.